# Session timout and authentication timeout values when application redirects user to login page in both timout cases

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, session-timeout

In my Asp.Net MVC 3 application, I have a custom session expiry handler attribute filter which checks if the session is expired before controller actions are invoked.

If the session has expired, the custom filter signs out the user from forms authentication and redirects the user to the login page. I am also aware that is the authorization fails for a user when accessing authorized content, the same flow of action will take place.

In this scenario, where a session OR authentication timout results in the same effect (the user being signed out of forms auth and redirected to login page), is it a major concern as to whether Timeout(Session) is greater or less than Timeout(authentication)?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, your authorization attributes would likely be the gate keeper here.
The concern is when your session times out before your forms auth token, such as in the case of an app pool restart. It sounds like you are handling this (if not I have code up on SO for this). In the opposite case you need to make sure you aren't relying on anything in the session for non-auth pages/actions otherwise you run the risk of expecting session values when a user could anonymously access the page. Beyond that I can't think if another scenarios that would cause an issue.

Your auth attributes should always catch this case and redirect to a login page where the session is started again.

Beware with session though- multiple requests for that user (ie Ajax requests) at the same time that access the session object will only be processed one at a time since the session is locked for that user by default behavior.

The other requests will literally hang until the other request accessing the session object is done. This isn't a problem if only the main request accesses the session but the other overlapping requests for that user (if there are any) don't.

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks for the prompt reply... My problem is that currently if authentication times out, OR session times out (irrelevant of which times out first), the user is signed out and redirected to the login page (in both timeout cases). In this implementation, should the session and authentication values relate in a particular way? Because in any case the user is going to have to login whichever authentication times out first.